# Kinect Calibration and Depth Image

Tags: openni, point-cloud-library

I have started looking at PCL and its SDK for Kinect. I am having a very basic problem. I have calibrated the RGB and IR cameras using RGBDemo with Checkerboard pattern as the control images. I have received the distortion coefficients and the offsets. I am having a problem of using the coefficients to receive a calibrated point cloud.

What I am trying to figure out is a procedure to receive the input depth image to implement the calibration model. I have found the `openni_wrapper::DepthImage`class with `getDepthMetaData().Data()`function which provides the depth in millimeters.

Is this the raw depth?

If not, is there another function to receive the raw depth image without prior calibration using PCL?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the information that can be found in the grabber tutorial:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php

You can change the tutorial to use either:

```
void (const boost::shared_ptr<openni_wrapper::DepthImage>&)
//This provides the depth image, without any color or intensity information
```

or

```
void (const boost::shared_ptr<openni_wrapper::Image>&, const  
      boost::shared_ptr<openni_wrapper::DepthImage>&, float constant)
// When a callback of this type is registered, the grabber sends both RGB image 
// and depth image and the constant (1 / focal length), which you need if you 
// want to do your own disparity conversion.
```

In the code this becomes:

```
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>

class KinectGrabber
{
public:
 void cloud_cb_ (const boost::shared_ptr<openni_wrapper::DepthImage> &depthImage)
 {
    // Do something with depthImage
 }

 void run ()
 {
   pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();

   boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<openni_wrapper::DepthImage>&)> f =
     boost::bind (&KinectGrabber::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

   interface->registerCallback (f);

   interface->start ();

   while (//place something to stop on)
   {
     //boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
     // or other function
   }

   interface->stop ();
 }
};

int main ()
{
   KinectGrabber v;
   v.run ();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then we cannot get the uncalibrated image using PCL and OpenNI? I have tried this and it seems that this already provides us with the final calibrated depth image with depth in mm. Raw depth images should have values from 0-2047 (11 bits) according to guides.